# Access any structure field chosen dynamically at run time

Tags: field, abap, corresponding-records

I have a problem, so I have a huge table where some fields contain only numbers from 1-20 and I want to move the values of the fields to a new table where there are 3 fields with a name and the number (zjdc01 or zadc01).

Now I want to check the field value from the huge table and append the values to the new fields.

For Example :

```
CASE LS_ATLAS_DC-ZJDC01.
    WHEN 1.
      LS_ATLAS-ZJDC01 = LS_ATLAS_DC-ZJDC01.
      LS_ATLAS-ZADC01 = LS_ATLAS_DC-ZADC01.
      LS_ATLAS-ZBDC01 = LS_ATLAS_DC-ZBDC01.
    WHEN 2.
      LS_ATLAS-ZJDC02 = LS_ATLAS_DC-ZJDC01.
      LS_ATLAS-ZADC02 = LS_ATLAS_DC-ZADC01.
      LS_ATLAS-ZBDC02 = LS_ATLAS_DC-ZBDC01.
    WHEN 3.
      LS_ATLAS-ZJDC03 = LS_ATLAS_DC-ZJDC01.
      LS_ATLAS-ZADC03 = LS_ATLAS_DC-ZADC01.
      LS_ATLAS-ZBDC03 = LS_ATLAS_DC-ZBDC01.
    WHEN 4.
      LS_ATLAS-ZJDC04 = LS_ATLAS_DC-ZJDC01.
      LS_ATLAS-ZADC04 = LS_ATLAS_DC-ZADC01.
      LS_ATLAS-ZBDC04 = LS_ATLAS_DC-ZBDC01.
```

But this is very exhausting and I think there is another Solution but I dont know if ABAP have something for this.

Maybe some of you have a Solution or have a similiar problem which he solved.

Comment: unfortunately no, because i still have to check if the value in zjdc01.
The Problem is in the huge table in the field ZJDC01 there are values like 10 or 2 or 5. 
So I have to check the field ZJDC01 and if the value is 2 I have to append this value to the new table with field name ZJDC02 and so on...

Comment: I don't understand, my answer corresponds exactly to your example code. So I guess your example code does not reflect exactly your question, could you clarify by updating it accordingly?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ASSIGN COMPONENT name OF STRUCTURE structure TO <field_symbol>`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapassign_mem_area_dynamic_dobj.htm).

```
DATA name TYPE string. " component name
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <zjdc_xx> TYPE any,
               <zadc_xx> TYPE any,
               <zbdc_xx> TYPE any.

IF number BETWEEN 1 and 4.

  name = |ZJDC{ number WIDTH = 2 ALIGN = RIGHT PAD = '0' }|.   "<== ZJDC01 to ZJDC04
  ASSIGN COMPONENT name OF STRUCTURE ls_atlas TO <zjdc_xx>.
  name = |ZADC{ number WIDTH = 2 ALIGN = RIGHT PAD = '0' }|.   "<== ZADC01 to ZADC04
  ASSIGN COMPONENT name OF STRUCTURE ls_atlas TO <zadc_xx>.
  name = |ZBDC{ number WIDTH = 2 ALIGN = RIGHT PAD = '0' }|.   "<== ZBDC01 to ZBDC04
  ASSIGN COMPONENT name OF STRUCTURE ls_atlas TO <zbdc_xx>.

  <zjdc_xx> = LS_ATLAS_DC-ZJDC01.
  <zadc_xx> = LS_ATLAS_DC-ZADC01.
  <zbdc_xx> = LS_ATLAS_DC-ZBDC01.

ENDIF.
```